# How can I make `.innerText` ignore invisible children of an invisible element?

Tags: javascript, innertext

Result of the test code below:

```
div[0].innerText === "aaaaa zzzzz"
div[1].innerText === "␤aaaaa␤invisible␤zzzzz␤"
```

How can I force `innerText` to give the same result for `div[1]` as it gives for `div[0]`?

I’ve tried to append `div[1]` to a temporary document but, since the document wasn’t actually displayed, it didn’t help. Only appending it to a literally visible document works.

#### Test code

```js
var div = [];
div[0] = document.getElementById("visible");
div[1] = div[0].cloneNode(true);

show(0);
show(1);

function show(i) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += 
      "<p>div[" + i + "].innerText === <code>" + 
      div[i].innerText.replace(/\n/g, "␤") + "</code></p>";
}
```

```css
#visible {display: block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: larger; color: red;}
code {background-color: lightgray; padding: 0 .318em;}
```

```html
<div id="visible">
<span style="display: inline">aaaaa</span>
<span style="display: none">invisible</span>
<span style="display: inline">zzzzz</span>
</div>

<div id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Is jQuery acceptable?

Comment: @DineiRockenbach: I think it's okay if you post a JQuery answer for the benefit of other users. I will upvote it but I will select only a pure Javascript answer as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only appending it to a document literally visible to the user works.

But the user doesn't necessarily have to see that. :-) If you append it, grab `innerText`, and then remove it, the user will never see it:

```js
var div = [];
div[0] = document.getElementById("visible");
div[1] = div[0].cloneNode(true);

show(0);
document.body.appendChild(div[1]);  // *****
show(1);
document.body.removeChild(div[1]);  // *****

function show(i) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += 
      "<p>div[" + i + "].innerText === <code>" + 
      div[i].innerText.replace(/\n/g, "␤") + "</code></p>";
}
```

```css
#visible {display: block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: larger; color: red;}
code {background-color: lightgray; padding: 0 .318em;}
```

```html
<div id="visible">
<span style="display: inline">aaaaa</span>
<span style="display: none">invisible</span>
<span style="display: inline">zzzzz</span>
</div>

<div id="output"></p>
```

Alternately, since the element isn't in the DOM, it can't be made invisible by CSS, only inline styles. I can't think of any other inline style that would make the text get left out of `innerText` other than your `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` (`opacity: 0`, for instance, doesn't do it), so it's trivial to exclude those and normalize whitespace for non-`pre` elements:

```
function getInnerText(element) {
  var node, text = "";
  if (element.style.display.toLowerCase() !== "none" && element.style.visibility.toLowerCase() !== "hidden") {
    for (node = element.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
      if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        text += node.nodeValue;
      } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        text += getInnerText(node);
      }
    }
  }
  // Normalize all whitespace if not "pre"
  if (element.tagName !== "PRE" && element.style.whiteSpace.toLowerCase().indexOf("pre") == -1) {
    text = text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  }
  return text;
}
```

That may well need tweaking (I don't think it handles `<div>stuff<pre>big      gap</pre></div>` properly), but you can run with the idea if you don't want to use the first solution above...

Example:

```js
var div = [];
div[0] = document.getElementById("visible");
div[1] = div[0].cloneNode(true);

show(0);
document.body.appendChild(div[1]);  // *****
show(1);
document.body.removeChild(div[1]);  // *****

function show(i) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += 
      "<p>div[" + i + "].innerText === <code>" + 
      getInnerText(div[i]).replace(/\n/g, "␤") + "</code></p>";
}

function getInnerText(element) {
  var node, text = "";
  if (element.style.display.toLowerCase() !== "none" && element.style.visibility.toLowerCase() !== "hidden") {
    for (node = element.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
      if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        text += node.nodeValue;
      } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        text += getInnerText(node);
      }
    }
  }
  // Normalize all whitespace if not "pre"
  if (element.tagName !== "PRE" && element.style.whiteSpace.toLowerCase().indexOf("pre") == -1) {
    text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
  }
  return text;
}
```

```css
#visible {display: block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: larger; color: red;}
code {background-color: lightgray; padding: 0 .318em;}
```

```html
<div id="visible">
<span style="display: inline">aaaaa</span>
<span style="display: none">invisible</span>
<span style="display: inline">zzzzz</span>
</div>

<div id="output"></p>
```

Comment: That’s a workaround I will resort to if no one finds a direct solution. Admittedly, not terrible.

Comment: After looking at this a bit I have to agree this is best. The only other thing you can really do is look for style attributes. But if visibility rules are applied by stylesheets this wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: @7vujy0f0hy: I've added an alternative. Since we don't have to worry about stylesheets, just inline styles, and there are only a couple of those that would cause the text to be left out, it's fairly straightforward to compute the inner text.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Your function looks encouraging. I wonder how compatible it is with the native `innerText` algorithm. You need a reasonable guarantee of compatibility when you want to compare live results against results held in a database generated by a process that doesn’t use your function. I had hoped that Javascript offered some “virtual visibility” mode for `innerText`.

Comment: @7vujy0f0hy: For high-fidelity results, you'll pretty much need to defer to the browser (the first solution above), but beware that different browsers have had different interpretations of `innerText`. The WHAT-WG have [now specified the property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-innertext), which is useful if you want to flesh out the function above and also b/c it encourages implementations to converge on that definition. That definition is not in the W3C version of the HTML spec, but the WHAT-WG is made up (partially) of vendors actually providing real-world browsers...