# Why does innerText render whitespaces on invisible elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this bit of code:

```
for (let x = 0; x < VALUE_INPUTS.length; x++) {
    const PROPERTY = {};
    let sibling = VALUE_INPUTS[x].parentElement.previousElementSibling;
    PROPERTY.unit = sibling.innerText;
    sibling = sibling.previousElementSibling;
    PROPERTY.name = sibling.innerText;
    console.log(PROPERTY);
    console.log(x);
}
```

Now when I look at the console, I can see the following being logged:

```
{unit: "↵                                            ↵    …        ↵                                        ", name: "1"}
0
{unit: "↵                                            ↵    …        ↵                                        ", name: "as"}
1
```

etc..

It iterates through the entire loop spitting out whitespaces everywhere. I would expect this kind of behavior from `innerHtml`, but not from `innerText`. Then it got even weirder, since I noticed that the last object looked like this (fine!):

```
{unit: "3", name: "3"}
```

When I looked into it, I found out that this only happens when the parent element of `VALUE_INPUTS[x]` has `display: none;`. I happened to have the last of the elements open, and the others were hidden. Causing the last object to be logged correctly.

Now I know I can easily solve this with `trim()`, but I'm wondering why this is happening? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060336/how-can-i-make-innertext-ignore-invisible-children-of-an-invisible-element) question looks somewhat similar but doesn't really explain why it's happening and is slightly different.